# Eclipse showing error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap at Jasper report calling

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We call Jasper report from Servlet and display pdf on Browser, the code is run one one system perfectly but when we try to run the code on another system it showing following error. Both systems configuration are same, and same version of Eclipse, and jar files but showing error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap

[image]

Comment: You should add *jar* with `org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap` at cp

Comment: jar with org.apache.commons.collections.map.ReferenceMap added at classpath but nothing to change. Same error :(

Comment: Do you have only one jar with this class at cp?